# Database Design Best Practice for webchat

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, chat

I'm designing a webchat that uses Pusher to handle the async calls.  It's for a game/tool I'm designing.  There can be any number of `games`, and each game has `channels` (for Pusher).  And each channel will open a new `session` after being inactive for 6 hours.

The messages need to be stored by session to access later.  So what would the best design for a database be?  Should I store the messages individually, or something like as json in a mysql text field?

Currently there's a table for games, game sessions, channels, chat sessions (linked 1:1 to game sessions), and one for the messages (with the messages in json format in a text field).  But I'm not sure if that's the best way to store what will amass to anywhere from 100-2000 messages in a single session, so storing each message in its own row sounds impractical.

Edit:  In terms of what I plan on doing with it.  I just need them archived so the users can view them by session again later.

So does that mean the best way would be to store each message in its own row with a unique id, and just filter all those out when loading the session?

Comment: That'll depend immensely on what you intend to do with the stored data.

Comment: 100-2000 is not a large amount in database terms. Even if that builds up to millions over time, it's still not a big issue these days, as long as the table is indexed properly. And you can always archive / delete old stuff.

Comment: Storing each message in it's own row sounds like exactly the right use of a database. You want many records, not many columns or many individual data points in a single field of a record. Index on the session id of that's how you will join over to this table (or filter this table via a WHERE clause) and you are good to go.

Comment: @JNevill Will that be fine even if the message body has no character limit?  Does that break how quickly the table can be accessed, or no since it's only comparing the `id` column when querying?